# Deadlock, Connection to the database is dropped

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an application that is connecting to a SQL server to run some inserts/updates. We've been getting deadlocks, But I’ve noticed that in addition to reporting the deadlock, the connection to the database is dropped and the client has to reconnect.

Is this normal? Even if it's not normal behaviour, is it possible that SQL server is not only deciding that my client will be the deadlock victim, but it is also terminating the connection?

Is there a way to stop the connection being dropped?

Comment: After further investigation the connection only seems to be disconnected for updates not queries how can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition a deadlock means two connections are stuck where SPID 1 has something locked that SPID 2 needs and SPID 2 has something locked that SPID 1 needs. Neither can complete their transaction because they need something the other has locked. In cases like this the server will choose a victim SPID and kill it so the other can complete its transaction.

The only way to stop it is to figure out why the deadlocks are occurring in the first place. You can run a trace to monitor deadlocks and capture the information relating to them into a diagram and then view the diagram in SSMS.

More information available here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/